# Function Loss for Unet Model in Image Segmentation

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I want to make a model for image segmentation with Unet. The dataset contains images with skin cancer, which are colored, and the masks,black and white, and I got a bit confused. The model is the classic one as in the code below but the thing is that the loss function plays a big role for the predictions on the Test set. I used 'binary_crossentropy' and 'mean_squared_error' and the predictions look pretty good for most images but I researched other loss functions and found about Dice Loss and when I used it for the model the results are quite bad(with the same number of Epochs and Batch Size). I am not sure what can cause this cause I've looked in other models for reference and with Dice Loss the results were good but for me it wasn't.
This is the model for the Unet:

```
def unet(Image_size):
    inply = Input(Image_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inply)
    conv1 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.2)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.2)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.2)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(pool4)

    convm = Conv2D(2 ** 10, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
    convm = Conv2D(2 ** 10, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(convm)

    tran5 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 9, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(convm)
    conc5 = Concatenate()([tran5, conv4])
    conv5 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(2 ** 9, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.1)(conv5)

    tran6 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 8, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop5)
    conc6 = Concatenate()([tran6, conv3])
    conv6 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(2 ** 8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)
    drop6 = Dropout(0.1)(conv6)

    tran7 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 7, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop6)
    conc7 = Concatenate()([tran7, conv2])
    conv7 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(2 ** 7, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
    drop7 = Dropout(0.1)(conv7)

    tran8 = Conv2DTranspose(2 ** 6, (2, 2), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(drop7)
    conc8 = Concatenate()([tran8, conv1])
    conv8 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conc8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(2 ** 6, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)
    drop8 = Dropout(0.1)(conv8)
    outly = Conv2D(2 ** 0, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop8)
    model = Model(inputs=inply, outputs=outly, name='U-net')

    return model
```

and these are my functions for Dice coeff and Dice loss, also added the IoU function cause I use it as a metric

```
def iou_score(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    union = K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) - intersection
    return intersection / union

def dice_score(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score


def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 1 - dice_score(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss
```

and how I call the compile methods:

```
model.compile(loss=dice_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', iou_score, dice_score])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', iou_score, dice_score])
```

I am not sure if the problem is how I define my functions or the model so I really appreciate if you have any idea what the cause would be. Thanks!